# jQuery get *exact* parent id

Tags: jquery, parent

I'd usually do $('ChildID').parent().attr('id'), but that would only get the first div with that id.

```
<div id="FOO1">
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
<div id="FOO2">
    <div id="bar" onClick="alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));"></div>
</div>
```

That would alert FOO1, but what I need it to do, is alert the actual parent, not the parent of the first div with such an id.

Comment: No, your code alerts `'FOO2'`. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/kDSBk/)

Comment: @imeVidas: beated you :D

Comment: @genesis I acknowledge your victory `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives me correctly FOO2

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/cbb12.php

Answer (score 2):

you shouldn't have more than one element with the same id... Also, if you're using jquery why are you using inline javascript?

html

```
<div id="FOO1">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div id="FOO2">
    <div id="foo" class="bar">click me</div>
</div>
```

js

```
$("#foo").click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/148/

Comment: It was just an example, takes up less space.. And they don't have the same id, they share a class, again, just an example..

Comment: well your example introduced a lot of potential problems. That can be very misleading for someone trying to debug.

Answer (score 0):

1. It alerts `FOO2` as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/HzDUy/
2. IDs must be unique within a document

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, this correctly returns `FOO2`. Your inconsistency is a result of the fact that you're using the same ID attribute on multiple elements. This abuse of the ID attribute can lead to odd behaviours since browsers are expecting each ID to be unique and may act differently.

I would *highly* recommend changing your `id=bar` attributes to classes, which are allowed to be duplicated, and will result in more predictable behaviour.

---

EDIT

Having noted your earlier comments, your code still returns the expected result of "FOO2" using the class attribute. Your error must be elsewhere in your code.